# R function not writing matrix with col indexing

Tags: r, function

I am trying to map values from a stochastic process. While in the past the following code produced a correct matrix with `number_draws` rows, it is not not working and giving me the following error:

```
Error in X[, i] <- Marginals_Beta_Var[U[, i], i] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

as well as turning X into a huge matrix with 10000x10000 dimension. Code:

```
number_draws = 10000
     X = matrix(nrow = number_draws, ncol = 18)

      for (i in 1:18){
        X[,i] =  Marginals_Beta_Var[U[, i], i]

      }
```

The Matrix U has indices for columns for mapping to other marginals

```
> head(U)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]   30    2  164  486   30  362  317   81  431   197   408   139   106   500   398   199
[2,]  275   40  217  173  172  366  218  205   96   255   184   255    38   328   375   175
[3,]  169  117  407  112  343   38   88  406  266    77    69   483    40   303   136   236
[4,]  245  261   54  364  287  224  320  246  446    71   340     7   250   360   341    75
[5,]  332  356  197  194  248  268  108  133  429   409   121   472   418   473   289   121
[6,]  328   60  160  310  181  411  183  499  339   350   354    28   104   278   444   210
     [,17] [,18]
[1,]    98   197
[2,]   469   205
[3,]   117    23
[4,]    39   457
[5,]   362   359
[6,]   329   304
```

Marginals_Beta_Var has 500 rows and 18 columns, each with a different value.

The code has previously worked. I am calling this within a function, perhaps I messed up the global values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming the type in "number_draws" (says "numbe_draws" instead) in your example here doesn't occur in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Marginals_Beta_Var[U[, i], i] is apparantly a tibble, could that be the problem?